# console input function doesn't terminate inside while loop

Tags: c++, loops, input

i want to create an easy user menu within the console,
where i can start some functions by typing in 1, 2, 3 ... but theres is a problem with the user input(inside the cap_console.cpp), since my program won't reach the if statements and it does not terminate.

My code so far:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cab_console.h"

int main(int argn, char ** argv){
    cab_console CONSOLE_MENU;
    CONSOLE_MENU.console();
}
```

cab_console.h

```
#ifndef CAB_CONSOLE_H
#define CAB_CONSOLE_H


class cab_console
{
public:
    char input;
    cab_console();

    void menu();
    void quit_console();
    void console();
};

#endif // CAB_CONSOLE_H
```

cab_console.cpp

```
void cab_console::console(){
char input = '0';
cout << "This is the menu." << endl;

while(input != 'Q') {
    cout << "Choose an action:" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Create ..." << endl;
    cout << "2 - Show ..." << endl;
    cout << "3 - Repeat ..." << endl;
    cout << "Q - Quit..." << endl;

    cin >> input;

    if(input == '1') {
        cout << "use function1 here..." << endl;
        cab_console::console();
    }
    if(input == '2'){
        cout << "use function2 here..." << endl;
        cab_console::console();
    }

    if(input == '3') {
        cout << "use function3 here..." << endl;
        cab_console::console();
    }
    if(input == 'Q'){
        cout << "Quit console..." << endl;
        cab_console::quit_console();
    }
    else{
        cout << "Its not a valid input.";
        cab_console::console();
    }
}
}
```

This is my Output

```
This is the menu.
Choose an action:
1 - Create ...
2 - Show ...
3 - Repeat ...
Q - Quit...
```

If i type in one of these, my program runs but as mentioned, it won't go into the if statements.

Many thanks

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Calling `cab_console::console()` from the `cab_console::console()` is very poor practice ( and doesn't compile at least on my platform). Don't do this, your call stack will fill up. Also post a [mcve]

Comment: Oh, there are more issues. For example you never do something like `cin >> input;`, how do you expect your menu to work??

Comment: Where are the implentations of `quit_console`? so this function must somehow get you out of the loop otherwise the program will be stuck in infinite loop/

Comment: @Jabberwocky It is inside the while loop `cout << "Q - Quit..." << endl;

    cin >> input;`

Comment: @NathanOliver oh, right... really weird code...

Comment: @Jabberwocky thx! I'll mind that. I've done this without recursion earlier but with a do-while loop and switch statements. Ended up in the same case. My "cin >> input" is inside the while loop

 sorry if its a weird code for you..im new to c++...

Comment: @Raindrop7 quit_console isn't implemented yet, but thats not the point. The point is that my input doesn't reach the if-statements, means there is no reaction on my input "1" or "2". Input should be "use function1 here...", "use function2 here..". Thx guys for your time

Comment: @Landau please [edit]  your code and post a __[mcve]__, something that we can compile and run on our computer and then hopefully give you some advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call `console` recursively.

What happens is that the first call to console would call another instance. Now the command you type is processed by the second instance that will call another instance and so on. When you type `Q` only the last instance terminates, leaving the others active and ready to take input.

Why don't you try something like the following instead? (note that there is not recursion involved).

```
bool valid_input(const char c){
 return c=='1' || c=='2' || c=='3' || c=='Q';   
}
char input='0';


while(input != 'Q') {


   do{
     cout << "Choose an action:" << endl;
     cout << "1 - Create ..." << endl;
     cout << "2 - Show ..." << endl;
     cout << "3 - Repeat ..." << endl;
     cout << "Q - Quit..." << endl;
     cin >> input;
   }while(!valid_input(input));


    if(input == '1') {
        cout<<"use function1 here...\n";

    }
    if(input == '2'){
        cout<<"use function2 here...\n";

    }

    if(input == '3') {
       cout<< "use function3 here...\n";

    }
    if(input == 'Q'){
      cout<< "use functionQ here...\n";
    }

}
```

Try it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E0jcIyaBzHJ5xmug)

Answer (score 1):

Recursively calling itself would be problematic, as mentioned in other places. 
Here is a quick example that uses a While loop to do what (I interpreted as what) you intended to do.  Adding additional write statements will help you, as well as learning to use a real debugger.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

char input = '0';
cout << "This is the menu." << endl;

while(input != 'Q') {

    cout << "Choose an action:" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Create ..." << endl;
    cout << "2 - Show ..." << endl;
    cout << "3 - Repeat ..." << endl;
    cout << "Q - Quit..." << endl;

    cin >> input;

    cout << "You enetered: " <<input << endl;

    if(input == '1') {
        cout<< "use function1 here..." << endl;;
    }
    else if(input == '2'){
        cout<< "use function2 here..." << endl;;
    }
    else if(input == '3') {
        cout<< "use function3 here..." << endl;
    }
    else if(input == 'Q'){
    cout << "Leaving so soon?" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Its not a valid input.";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```